# how to get a view from an event coordinates in android when view set rotation?

Tags: android, view, coordinates, touch-event

I have method for event coordinates touch inside view target.

```
public boolean isInsideView( View view,float x, float y){
        int location[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationInWindow(location);
        int viewX = location[0];
        int viewY = location[1];

        if(( x > viewX && x < (viewX +  view.getWidth())) &&
                ( y > viewY && y < (viewY + view.getHeight()))){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But not work when view target is set rotation.

```
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/v_checkpoint1_1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:rotation="-25" />
```

please help me for fix this.
very thank.

Comment: This answer seems to be useful to solve the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096469/how-to-get-the-proper-bounds-of-a-view-after-transformation-matrix